# how to add a uitab bar controller with non of the tab get selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added an UITabBarController. My requirement is to display a view with tab bar controller. but that view is not part of the tab bar items. For example my tab bar contains 3 tabs

1. contacts
2. camera
3. history

Generally if we add tabbar controller contacts will be get selected and that view will be displayed automatically. but i don't want in that way...

i used [tabBarcontroller setSelectedViewController=nil];

i am able to get a tab bat with non of the tab get selected. but when i am trying to select a tab item it's not working.. I think i set the selectedViewController to nil. is there any other way to achieve my requirements...?

please explain your answer clearly.. i am new to iphone app development..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present a view controller which is not a part of your tab bar controller and put a tab bar image/buttons at the bottom of it which resembles your tab bar. When you receive a button pressed message from within that view controller, show that tab on screen.

Comment: Great answer! I just verified that you can create a tab bar in code, give it labels (didn't test images), and nothing is selected - so you can use that as your image:  UITabBarItem *i1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"One" image:nil tag:0];
 UITabBarItem *i2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Two" image:nil tag:0];
 UITabBar *tb = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 44)];
 tb.items = @[i1, i2];